# iptables redirected port 80 to 8080 - How to disallow direct access to port 8080?

Tags: iptables, tomcat, port-forwarding, port-80

I've routed all requests from port 80 to port 8080 for my Tomcat server using iptables.

`iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

Now `http://mydomain.com/` works fine, but people can still access `http://mydomain.com:8080`. I see that on other sites this is not possible. Is there anyway to disable direct access to port 8080 via the url?

Comment: Is there a reason not to simply run your Tomcat server on port 80 natively?

Comment: Apparently that requires giving root access to the Tomcat user and that it's generally a bad idea. That's what I've read, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access http://mydomain.com, does it rewrite the URL to http://mydomain.com:8080? If it does, I don't see how to make it work using purely iptables (because you will need the 8080 port to be open to answer the requests). I did a quick test here and the URL was being rewritten but it may be my site doing it.

Said that, maybe it's better to put a [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) or apache with [ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) in front of your application to deal with URLs, with the plus of being able to use `nginx`'s or `apache`'s URL rewrite, load balancing and other capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been using iptables for very long now so I wouldn't know how to write the rules for you but I believe if you drop or reject all requests for port 8080 in the filter table then put the statement you provided in the postrouting chain you will get your desired result.

I'm still trying to learn iptables so if this is wrong could you tell me why in the comments?